# Laravel inertiajs not rendering head

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm trying to render a different head for every page with Laravel inertia:

```
<title inertia>My title...</title>

<meta name="description" content="My page..." />
```

In a vue page:

```
import { Head } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
    
<Head>
    <title inertia>Your page title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Your page description" inertia />
</Head>
```

However, the page source is not changed based on the current page. What am I missing here?